# If an outdoor outlet is mounted flush and the cabling direct through the wall, can I use indoor cabling?

Tags: electrical

If I drill a hole from indoors to outdoors and mount an exterior outlet directly over the hole, do I need to use outdoor cabling even though it's not exposed to the elements?

Answer (score 1):

Although it's done that way *all the time*, it's my opinion that if the box is in a wet location, the cable inside the box must be rated for wet locations.  Sometimes an easy way to comply is set a box just inside the building, and transition from NM to UF in the indoor box, send the UF out to the outdoor box.

Comment: Or run it the last foot in conduit, and use THWN-2 individual wires.